# How should we score programs in languages that tokenize instructions?

Tags: discussion, scoring

I feel like this should be said, because many answers have been made in TI-BASIC, Applesoft BASIC, and other languages that tokenize instructions. How exactly should they be scored? Should we score them as plain UTF-8 or by how they are stored in memory? Are there any exceptions? Thank you so much, PPCG Meta.

Comment: To use the words in your question, one should almost always use the byte count of how they are stored in memory, minus header information like the file name (so long as it is not significant to the program).

Comment: `there must be an actual file with the claimed byte count that, when fed to your interpreter, runs the intended program` https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13111/65836