# Can I use my SBCS for Uiua?

Tags: discussion, support

I just made a single-byte encoding for [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/).
If you are interested, [here](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgZW5jb2RpbmcgZm9yIFVpdWEgMC44LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgMjcgRGVjZW1iZXIgMjAyMwojIEFQTCdzICLijbUiIGlzIHVzZWQgYXMgYSBwbGFjZWhvbGRlci4KCkNPTlRST0wg4oaQICJcMOKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNtVxu4o214o21XHLijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbUiClBSSU5UQUJMRSDihpAgIiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0-P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX7ijbUiClVJVUEg4oaQICLiiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYXiiaDiiaTiiaXDl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4oSC4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmtwqTii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHii5XiiY3iip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_imIfihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipfiiKfiiLXiiaHiip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziipDii4XiipniiKnCsOKMheKNnOKKg-KqvuKKk-KLlOKNouKsmuKNo-KNpOKGrOKGq-Kags63z4DPhOKInuK4ruKGkOKVreKUgOKVt-KVr-KfpuKfp-KMnOKMn-KVk-KVn-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) is the Pad.
According to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5879/117598) answer (which seems to be commonly linked to),

> An answerer can use whatever encoding they want for a particular answer.

The comments on that answer imply that the encoding must exist beforehand and not be ad hoc.
I made this encoding specifically for use on Stack Exchange, but not for any question in particular.
There didn't seem to be any existing/standard SBCS for Uiua, and it would be nice for the # of characters to correspond to the # of bytes.

- Can I use my new encoding on new answers?
- Can I use my new encoding on old answers? (At the moment, I only have one answer in Uiua.)
- Can anyone use my new encoding for old and new answers?

EDIT: for anyone reading this in the future, the answers to these questions are yes! Just be sure to say that you are using the SBCS (and probably link it).

Comment: [This already has an answer here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14330/78850)

Comment: Note that the set of characters used by Uiua is changing frequently, so an implementation on any fixed set of chars won't work long term. On the other hand, we can always count the chars on the glyph bar (which is 111 at the moment, including ascii chars), and thus assume that a 8-bit encoding exists that can encode ascii range plus all unicode glyphs. This is why many answers link [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/78410) as the implementation of such an SBCS.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that implementation after making mine. I think I will still prefer to use mine, for a few reasons (up to date currently, no duplicate codepoints, drawing characters used in pretty printing, room for expansion into x00-1f)